# Flex-lex: Match r if there is something in front of it

Tags: flex-lexer

Using flex,

how do you match something when there is something in front of it.

for example: If there is R before D print something

I tried

`{something}/D          {printf("V");}`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how (f)lex works. (F)lex is a *tokeniser*; it splits the input into consecutive tokens. At each point in the input, it selects the appropriate token starting at precisely that point; the next token will start at the end of the previous token.

If you want to recognize certain tokens only in some particular context, you can use [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html), but it is your responsibility to notice context changes. So you could, for example, change to a different start condition in the action associated with any token which ends with an `R`:

```
%x AFTER_R
%%
[[:alpha:]]+   { if (yytext[yyleng-1] == 'R') BEGIN(AFTER_R);
                 /* handle this token */
               }
  /* Etc. for other patterns which might end with an R */
<AFTER_R>"D"   { puts("Found a D after an R"); }
```

Excessive use of start conditions can make lexical description files hard to read and debug; it may indicate that your problem is not well-suited to the (f)lex tokenizing model.